# How does jQuery simulate `focusin` event in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I read [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin) that says

> This event is not yet supported in Firefox, see bug 687787. It is possible to use the focus event instead, which is also compatible with event delegation.

The [latest jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/focusin.js) says

```
// Support: Firefox
// Firefox doesn't have focus(in | out) events
// Related ticket - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787
// Support: Chrome, Safari
// focus(in | out) events fire after focus & blur events, 
// which is spec violation - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-focusevent-event-order
// Related ticket - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449857
```

I created the following jsFiddle page to test if the `focusin` event is working or not in Firefox. It seems working. Note: I am aware that this event `focus()` event itself is called through jQuery object, but even if I manually click on any of the squares, Firefox does fire the event.

https://jsfiddle.net/beatak/8grhLusj/14/

I care more about if I can use `focusin/out` events with jQuery in a cross-browser fashion, and clearly, it works okay with Firefox. I'm not familiar with what `jQuery.event.simulate()` does and I wonder if someone can explain how that works in Firefox so that I'm more confident to use jQuery's simulated `focusin/out` events.

Comment: But...your fiddle binds the focusin handler *with jQuery*, so you're not testing whether Firefox supports focusin, you're testing whether jQuery simulates it... If you specifically want to test Firefox's support you should bind your event handier with addEventListener().

Comment: P. S.  The jQuery source code that you link to in your question *is* the code that simulates the event, isn't it?

Comment: You're right. I care more about if I can use `focusin/out` events with jQuery. I'm not familiar with what `jQuery.event.simulate()` does and I wonder if someone can explain how that works in Firefox so that I'm more confident to use jQuer's `focusin/out`.

Comment: I believe you'll be fine in Firefox as long as you use jQuery for these events. As your test already showed. (Sorry, I don't have time to go through jQuery source code to figure out how it does it.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. it made me realize that I should clarify the question. updated.